# conflicting dtoverlays

Tags: gpio, display, kernel, ds18b20

I'm using a GPIO connected display [1](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DPi-35/) which requires a patched kernel and dtoverlay=4dpi-3x in /boot/config.txt
I would like to use a DS18B20 temperature sensor which requires dtoverlay=w1-gpio to show the temperature on the display.

If I try to load both overlays at the same time seperated by ',' only the first one will work. So either the display or the DS18B20. Is there another way to make them work together?

The display does not use GPIO4 which the DS18B20 is connected to.

Comment: Have you tried without the comma? Note examples all show one per line. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md

Comment: /boot/overlays/README indicates that they are to be separated by comma I'll give it a try anyways.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As it turns out several overlays can be loaded by adding multiple dtoverlay variables:

In this case:

```
dtoverlay=4dpi-3x
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```